# R: Error!! : object of type 'S4' is not subsettable

Tags: r

I am working with "*rehh*" package of R.

I create an object chr21 of class haplohh from data2haplohh function of the package.

Now when I try to write it to a file:

```
 write.table(chr21, file = "CHR21", append = FALSE, quote = TRUE,sep = "\t", eol="\n", na= "NA", dec=".", row.names=TRUE, col.names=TRUE)
```

The error I get is:

> Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) :
>     cannot coerce class "structure("haplohh", package = "rehh")" to a data.frame

Also when I try to print first 10 rows of chr21,

```
head(chr21, n=10)
```

I get this error:

> Error in x[seq_len(n)] : object of type 'S4' is not subsettable

OK so am adding the output of *str(chr21)*:

> str(chr21)
>
> Formal class 'haplohh' [package "rehh"] with 6 slots
>
> ..@ haplo   : num [1:10, 1:1010554] 0 2 2 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 ...
>
> ..@ position: num [1:1010554] 9411410 9411645 9411785 9412503 9413228 ...
>
> ..@ snp.name: chr [1:1010554] "rs78200054" "rs71235074" "rs71235075" "rs71220884" ...
>
> ..@ chr.name: chr "21"
>
> ..@ nhap    : int 10
>
> ..@ nsnp    : int 1010554

I am a newbie in R, It would be really great If I could get to know where I am going wrong and how to fix this error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide the `chr21` object. It's very difficult to guess what the problem is without knowing the input object. Consider also that `write.csv` accepts only `data.frame`s objects or an objecti coercibl to `data.frame`.

Comment: there probably are specific methods to reach the different slots of your object

Comment: Can you add to your question the output of the following command str(chr21). This will help to identify why you are getting this error.

Comment: @Katia : pls check the question now

Comment: @nicola : I have added some info in the question. Please check

Comment: @user8393448 See my answer and let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(rehh)

#Copy example files in the current working directory.
make.example.files()

#Chreate some sampel data 
chr12<-data2haplohh(hap_file="bta12_hapguess_switch.out",map_file="map.inp",
                  min_maf=0.05,popsel=7,chr.name=12,recode.allele=TRUE)

# Look at the structure of the object (in your case it is called chr21)
str(chr12)
Formal class 'haplohh' [package "rehh"] with 6 slots
..@ haplo   : num [1:280, 1:1202] 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 ...
..@ position: num [1:1202] 79823 125974 175087 219152 256896 ...
..@ snp.name: chr [1:1202] "F1200140" "F1200150" "F1200170" "F1200180" ...
..@ chr.name: chr "12"
..@ nhap    : int 280
..@ nsnp    : int 1202
```

You can extract various components from this object:

```
# Extract data matrix from it
haplo.matrix <- chr12@haplo

# Extract position
pos <- chr12@position
head(pos)
#[1]  79823 125974 175087 219152 256896 316254
```

If you need to get data back into a dataframe format you can do the following:

```
df <- data.frame(chr=chr12@chr.name, snp.name=chr12@snp.name, position=chr12@position, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df <- cbind(df, t( chr12@haplo))
```

Once this is done, you can use head() and other regular R functions. 
However if you need to apply the functions from rehh package you should use original chr21 object